# regex.replace not replacing anything

Tags: c#, regex

I want to replace `\"` characters in a string like `\"someword\"`. But this regex  `"(\\\")+"` doesn't work.

```
Regex.Replace(string_, "(\\\")+", String.Empty);
```

Comment: Is the task to just replace `"` with empty string? Then you do not need any regex, just `s = old_s.Replace("\"", string.Empty);`.

Comment: yes that is finally what i did. And now it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
var myNewString = Regex.Replace(string_, "(\\\")+", String.Empty);
```

as you can see from [MSDN Regex.Replace documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z(v=vs.110).aspx) this method has a return value of type `string`

The documentation states that this value is:

> **Return Value**
>
> **Type: System.String**
>
> A new string that is identical to the
>   input string, except that the replacement string takes the place of
>   each matched string. If pattern is not matched in the current
>   instance, the method returns the current instance unchanged.

Comment: Note that `"(\\\")+"` is in fact `\"+` regex, and is equal to just `"+` as a double quote does not need to be escaped. Is the task to just replace `"` with empty string?

Answer (score 2):

## Non-escaped quote removal

If your task is just to remove all non-escaped double quotes, you do not need any regex, just use

```
s = old_s.Replace("\"", string.Empty);
```

## Literally-escaped quotes

In case you can have more than just a double quote escaped in your input, you'd need a more robust solution that will keep all other escaped symbols intact. It is possible to do with a match evaluator:

```
var old_text= @"\\""someword\"""; // Literal \\"someword\", escaped backslash at the start
var stext = Regex.Replace(old_text, @"\\(.)", 
               m => m.Groups[1].Value == "\"" ? "\"" : m.Groups[1].Value);
```

Result - only the last `"` is changed as it is the only literally escaped double quote:

[image]

Comment: If your task is just to remove all `"`s, you do not need any regex, just  use `s = old_s.Replace("\"", string.Empty);`.